# Jenkins pipeline skip stage if copying fails

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy

Let's say we have a simple pipeline setup like this:

```
pipeline {
   stages {
      stage('Stage1') {
         sh '''
           echo 'Copying files'
           cp ./file1 ./directory1
         '''
      }
      stage('Stage2') {
         sh '''
           echo 'This stage should still work and run'
           cp ./directory2/files ./directory2/subdirectory
         '''
      }
      stage('Stage3') { ... }
      ...
   }
}
```

Whenever I don't have the files in Stage1 or Stage2, it fails the build saying:

`'cp cannot stat ./file1 ./directory1'` or `'cp cannot stat ./directory2/files ./directory2/subdirectory'`

Of course if the files exist, both stages work perfectly fine. The problem is that the build fails for the rest of the stages if a stage fails. So if Stage1 fails because there are no files, it fails every stage after and they don't even run, same goes for if Stage2 fails, then we know that Stage1 succeeded but then Stage3 and onwards fails and does not even run.

Is there a way to make it so that if the `cp` command fails and the `cp cannot stat` shows, to just skip the stage and proceed to the next one? Or at least make it so that only that stage fails and it can proceed to build the next stage(s)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check if the file exists and only then copy?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an simple way of skipping the stage when a file does not exist, using the `when` directive:

```
pipeline {
   agent any   
   stages {
      stage('Stage1') {
         when { expression { fileExists './file1' } }
         steps {
            sh '''
            echo 'Copying files'
            cp ./file1 ./directory1
            '''
         }
      }
      stage('Stage2') {
         when { expression { fileExists './directory2/files' } }
         steps {
            sh '''
            echo 'This stage should still work and run'
            cp ./directory2/files ./directory2/subdirectory
            '''
         }
      }
      stage('Stage3') {
         steps {
            echo "stage 3"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In above case you have to specify the path twice, in the `when` directive and in the sh step, it is better to handle it in a another way e.g. using variables or closures.
Because of the restrictions in the declarative pipeline, I would recommend you to use the scripted pipeline instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `catchError`

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                script{
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    echo 'Copying files'
                    cp ./file1 ./directory1
                }
              }
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                script{
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    echo 'This stage should still work and run'
                    cp ./directory2/files ./directory2/subdirectory
                }
              }
            }
        }

        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From above pipeline script, all stages will executed. If the `cp` command will not work for either of stage 1 or stage 2, it will show as failed for that particular stage but rest all stages will execute.

Similar to below screenshot:

[image]

---

**Modified Answer**

Following pipeline script include `sh ''' '''`, which need not have to be present inside the `catchError` block.

You can include only those commands inside `catchError` for which you want to catch the errors.

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh """
                
                echo 'Hello World!!!!!!!!'
                curl https://www.google.com/
                
                """ 

                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    echo 'Copying files'
                    cp ./file1 ./directory1
                }
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    echo 'This stage should still work and run'
                    cp ./directory2/files ./directory2/subdirectory
                }
            }
        }

        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for the script {} ?

Comment: In this case, you can or cannot use `script {}`. It is used to execute scripts in declarative pipeline. Totally depends you want to have `script{}` or not.

Comment: Ah, so I forgot to include that i have an ```sh ''' ... '''``` in each stage. Could you update your code so that it is inclusive with my ```sh ''' ... '''```. I presume that you wouldn't need a script {} if I have an ```sh ''' '''``` correct?

Also if I have other bash/linux commands above the ```cp``` command, do I include that in the catchError or is only the ```cp``` lines in the catchError?

Comment: No, it doesn't require `script{}` in order to run `sh ''' '''`. Also, you can add those bash/linux commands for which you want to catch the error using  `catchError`. Here, you can only have `cp` commands inside the `catchError`. I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the file exists before you try to copy it using a conditional like this:

`[ -f ./directory2/files ] && cp ./directory2/files ./directory2/subdirectory || echo "File does not exist"`

[Source and more info](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html)